# GDAL/ogr2ogr/ogrinfo produces an invalid pointer error each time I run it

Tags: pointers, gdal, coredump, ogr2ogr

After installing ogr2ogr following the steps described here
https://mothergeo-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development/how-to/gdal-ubuntu-pkg.html

When I run either ogr2ogr or ogrinfo, I get the following error message

> free(): invalid pointer

AFTER the execution of the command. Any advice to clean that?

ogrinfo --version
GDAL 3.3.2, released 2021/09/01
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)

-- Edit --

I may have found some kind of tip here.
mail-archive.com/gdal-dev@lists.osgeo.org/msg36151.htmllibproj

Excerpt :

> so your GDAL is linking against 2 PROJ versions libproj.so.15 and libproj.so.19. Make sure your libspatialite and libgeotiff versions are from the ubuntugis PPA, so they link gainst libproj.so.19 and no .so.15

Now I need to find a way to remove one library, without breaking my os...

Answer (score 6):

There's a bug regarding linking against 2 PROJ versions libproj.so.15 and libproj.so.19

For Debian/Ubuntu, you can do to remedy it

```bash
sudo apt purge gdal-bin -y
sudo rm -f /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.15
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.19 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.15
sudo apt install gdal-bin -y
```

Comment: Had the same error, ran these commands but still getting the error